# What is the meaning of .=+ in Julia?

Tags: performance, optimization, julia

I'm new to Julia and I'm trying to make my program as efficient as possible.
My program has to compute a lot with matrices, and I stumbled across the broadcast operator, which sped up everything by a lot.
However now I found another peculiar way to do a calculation.

The first version was: (both being NxN matrices)
`

```
hist .= hist .+ mask
```

My algorithm including this line ran in about 1 second per iteration.

Now I thought lets be smart and combine `.=` and `.+` So i tried `.+=`, since `+=` works and I just had to broadcast it. However as you might know this did not work.

By accident I tried this version of my code:

```
hist .=+ mask
```

And surprisingly this cut down the runtime to 0.2sec

Can someone explain to me the meaning of `.=+` and why it is not `.+=`? Or is it even the same?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
my IDE was the issue why `.+=` didnt work. It however is the right way to do it!

Comment: Isn't that just `hist .= +mask` which means `hist .= mask` and thus very different of `hist .+= mask`. Did you check the results?

Comment: `.+=` is indeed the correct way to broadcast `+=`, so I'm not sure why you say that "as you might know this did not work." It should work. On the other hand, `.=+` is a nonsensical operator, and probably just does `.=`

Comment: thanks for clarifying. For some reason .+= threw an error so i assumed that .=+ is the right way to do it. I appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `.=+` is not an operator in Julia. You are looking for `.+=`.

To explain the behavior you observed, `hist .=+ mask` parses as `hist .= (+mask)` which, in this case, is equivalent to the broadcasted assignment `hist .= mask` which assigns every element of `mask` to its corresponding element of `hist`. This is faster than `hist .+= mask` because `.=+` is not doing what you thaught it was. It skips the addition.